# Javascript Date var to Razor DateTime

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a jquery datepicker in my .NET MVC5 application. I need to convert the javascript Date var to a Razor DateTime var, after a user selects the correct date. Then I can send it back to the controller. Since Razor is server side and javascript client side, how can we solve this? Check out my code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-inline">
    <h4>Reservation</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Date:<input type="text" id="date1" class="datefield" /></p>
        <p>Date:<input type="text" id="date2" class="datefield" /></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#date1").on('click', function () {
                    var minDate = $("#date1").val();
                })
                $("#date2").on('click', function () {
                    var maxDate = $("#date2").val();
                })


        });
        </script>

        @{DateTime minDateCC = DateTime.Now; DateTime maxDateCC = DateTime.Now;}

        <script type="text/javascript">
            minDate = Date(@minDateCC);
            maxDate = Date(@maxDateCC);
        </script>

        @Html.ActionLink("Show Available Campingspots Per Date", "ShowAvailableSpotsPerDate", new { minDateCC, maxDateCC })

    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: You can't do like this and why you want to do this?

Comment: I want the user to pick a from and end date, and show the camping spots that are available between those 2 dates.

Comment: Javascript will be posted via form and c# will handle it on action itself

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that? How can I have @minDateCC have the value of 'minDate' when the user clicks the ActionLink? It's not really a submit as you would normally have in a form

Comment: Put a name for your input and use a submit button instead of ActionLink. Then in controller action you can retrieve your dates with FormCollection["nameYouGave"]. This will be a string so you have to convert to DateTime.

Comment: @Forza you need to submit a form via input fields or use ajax